# Processing list of objets in SendGrid

Tags: java, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates, sendgrid-api-v2

I want to show a table in my email list of objets in SendGrid. The table should look like following. There are dynamic number of rows in the table. How should I send the data from java code or design it in SendGrid?

```html
<html>
<table style="width: 1px; height: 1px;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>heading1</td>
<td>heading2</td>
<td>heading3</td>
<td>heading4</td>
<td>heading5</td>
<td>heading6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide more code - what have you tried so far? What is the java code?

Comment: I am not sure what should I send from java. Should it be string/object/json?

Comment: So you haven't tried then? it sounds like you can use a google search to resolve this. SendGrind does offer code documentation.

Comment: I tried sending HTML but it's not allowing the large size of data I have, and didn't find any way how can sendgrid process a List or json. I have already done a lot of google search and read all the documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sendgrid doesn't provide a way to show table on the mail. I created an excel file and added it to the attachment.